# Three-way Mixed ANOVA (BBW) - sig vs no sig interactions, what now?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures

I'm desperately trying to have an answer for this, but no luck so far.

**My RQ:**

- Do students experience increased anxiety prior to their first laboratory (yes)
- Can a short intervention reduce this initial anxiety
- Is there a difference between gender (males vs females) or laboratory experience (Short vs Long)

n ≈ 300 /year.65% females, 35% males.70% attend long laboratory, 30% attend short laboratory

**Study design:** Anxiety Measure 1 (continuous variable) ---> Intervention ---> Anxiety Measure 2 (same survey) ---> Attend first lab --> Anxiety measure 3 (same survey, post lab)

I figured Three-way mixed ANOVA BBW.

- The dependent variable is anxiety score.
- The 1st between subjects factor is gender (two groups: male and female).
- The 2nd between subject factor is lab experience (Two groups, long and short).
- The within-subject factor is time (which has three time points, T1, T2, and T3).

**Problem (when I follow Laerd Statistics)**

- Step 1: Do you have a statistically significant three-way interaction?  -→ No
- Step 2: Do you have any statistically significant two-way interactions? -→ No
- Laerd: If no – you do not have any statistically significant simple two-way interactions – end analysis and write up.

If I listen to Laerd, there is nothing to write. However, by looking for significant simple main effects, however: I found that **males reported lower anxiety levels when compared to females at T1 (p = 0.015).**
By further looking into simple simple main effects, I found that at **T1, males in the longer lab show higher anxiety than females in the longer labs.**
And .... at T2, males in the longer lab show higher anxiety than females in the longer labs.
Of course, the most important aspect is overall anxiety (Regardless of gender or laboratory experience) significantly decreased across all three time points (suggesting the intervention works (T2 - T1), and initial heightened anxiety was present (T3 - T1).

My confusion is, if I follow Laerd's stats, I only talk about not having three way interactions and two way interactions... However, as you can see, I have quite a bit of findings.

I am facing this issue across another cohort as well (dif year), where another intervention showed no three way interaction, but a two way interaction. However, according to Laerd, I can't look at simple simple comparisons for some reason.

Comment: Please provide the relevant model output by editing the question. Did you do a power study prior to collecting data ?